# How to find/match/select identifier name in Neo4j

Tags: java, database, neo4j

I've been working on **Neo4j** recently and i know basic rules and how to select property names. However , i need to get the identifier name.

Here is the code:

> CREATE (Jugan:Person {name:'George'})

I **DON'T** want to find 'George' name, but i wanna get the identifier name that is '**Jugan**'.

When i write something with " match and return " stuff , i wanna get this "Jugan" name. I hope i explained clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiers are *not* persisted at all. Their lifetime is just the current statement and their main usage is to refer back to a known node e.g. for returning them.

So no luck finding `Jugan` in your example. Introduce a property for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a label.  When you return you can use the `LABELS()` function like so:

```
RETURN labels(node)
```

Since nodes can have zero or more labels, this will give you an array.